# Reactjs => Dynamic active menu change color

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm having a problem here when I want to make dynamic color changes when the user wants to click on the menu in the sidebar.

So, when the user wants to move the page from /building to /street, then the user will click the "street" menu and hopefully the street menu will change color like the building menu which changes color to red when the menu is active.

however, when I made it not as I expected and the result is like the image below.

Maybe the masters can help me. Thank you very much

[image]
[image]

***Sidebar.jsx***

```
import React from "react";
import { useState } from "react";
import { BiBuildingHouse } from "react-icons/bi";
import { FaRoad } from "react-icons/fa";
import { Link, NavLink } from "react-router-dom";

const Sidebar = () => {
  const [activeMenu, setActiveMenu] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div className='w-[16rem] h-[72rem] bg-[#FFFFFF] px-5 py-3 md:px-8 md:py-5 drop-shadow-xl"'>
      <h1 className="text-[#92929D] font-semibold ml-3">DASHBOARD</h1>

      <NavLink
        to="/try/building"
        className={
          activeMenu === "/try/building"
            ? "mr-6 mt-4 w-[12rem] h-[4rem] bg-red-500 text-white py-3 md:px-8 md:py-5 rounded-2xl drop-shadow-xl cursor-pointer"
            : "mr-6 mt-4 text-black py-3 md:px-8 md:py-5 rounded-2xl drop-shadow-xl cursor-pointer"
        }
        onClick={() => {
          setActiveMenu("/try/building");
        }}
        active={activeMenu}
      >
        <div className="mr-6 mt-4 w-[12rem] h-[4rem] bg-red-500 py-3 md:px-8 md:py-5 rounded-2xl drop-shadow-xl cursor-pointer">
          <div className="inline-flex gap-4 items-center">
            <BiBuildingHouse size={25} className="text-white" />
            <h1 className="text-white">Building</h1>
          </div>
        </div>
      </NavLink>

      <Link
        to="/try/street"
        className={
          activeMenu === "/try/street"
            ? "mr-6 mt-4 w-[12rem] h-[4rem] bg-red-500 text-white py-3 md:px-8 md:py-5 rounded-2xl drop-shadow-xl cursor-pointer"
            : "mr-6 mt-4 text-black py-3 md:px-8 md:py-5 rounded-2xl drop-shadow-xl cursor-pointer"
        }
        onClick={() => {
          setActiveMenu("/try/street");
        }}
        active={activeMenu}
      >
        <div className="mr-6 w-[12rem] h-[4rem] py-3 md:px-8 md:py-5 rounded-2xl drop-shadow-xl cursor-pointer">
          <div className="inline-flex gap-4 items-center">
            <FaRoad size={25} className="text-[#92929D]" />
            <h1 className="text-black">Street</h1>
          </div>
        </div>
      </Link>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Sidebar;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `useState()` like that, you either have one state for text or for boolean.
You need to use it like this:

```
const [activeMenu, setActiveMenu] = useState(false);
const [activeLink, setActiveLink] = useState("");
```

Secondly, you can't use `activeMenu` for both links, you don't need this `active={activeMenu}` at all.

Please use simple CSS, whatever library you use must have a `classname:active`,
or simply add:

```
.my_className {
    background: white;
    color: black;
}
.my_className:active, .my_className:selected, .my_className:hover {
    background: red;
}
```

then add the `my_className` to every menu item.

more easy way you can use [ant.desgin](https://ant.design/components/layout/) library, very straight forward and easy to implement.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue with the current code is that all links are attempting to use the same `activeMenu` state. Neither the `NavLink` nor `Link` components consume an `active` prop though.

The `NavLink` component already applies an `active` class by default, and can otherwise already handle the logic you are trying to do manually. The `className` prop can also take a callback function that is passed an `isActive` prop when it matches the current URL pathname.

Example:

```
const Sidebar = () => {
  return (
    <div className='w-[16rem] h-[72rem] bg-[#FFFFFF] px-5 py-3 md:px-8 md:py-5 drop-shadow-xl"'>
      <h1 className="text-[#92929D] font-semibold ml-3">DASHBOARD</h1>

      <NavLink
        to="/try/building"
        className={({ isActive }) => 
          isActive
            ? "mr-6 mt-4 w-[12rem] h-[4rem] bg-red-500 text-white py-3 md:px-8 md:py-5 rounded-2xl drop-shadow-xl cursor-pointer"
            : "mr-6 mt-4 text-black py-3 md:px-8 md:py-5 rounded-2xl drop-shadow-xl cursor-pointer"
        }
      >
        <div className="mr-6 mt-4 w-[12rem] h-[4rem] bg-red-500 py-3 md:px-8 md:py-5 rounded-2xl drop-shadow-xl cursor-pointer">
          <div className="inline-flex gap-4 items-center">
            <BiBuildingHouse size={25} className="text-white" />
            <h1 className="text-white">Building</h1>
          </div>
        </div>
      </NavLink>

      <NavLink
        to="/try/street"
        className={({ isActive }) => 
          isActive
            ? "mr-6 mt-4 w-[12rem] h-[4rem] bg-red-500 text-white py-3 md:px-8 md:py-5 rounded-2xl drop-shadow-xl cursor-pointer"
            : "mr-6 mt-4 text-black py-3 md:px-8 md:py-5 rounded-2xl drop-shadow-xl cursor-pointer"
        }
      >
        <div className="mr-6 w-[12rem] h-[4rem] py-3 md:px-8 md:py-5 rounded-2xl drop-shadow-xl cursor-pointer">
          <div className="inline-flex gap-4 items-center">
            <FaRoad size={25} className="text-[#92929D]" />
            <h1 className="text-black">Street</h1>
          </div>
        </div>
      </Link>
    </div>
  );
};
```